# Stream transformer Monad for Vector.Stream

Tags: haskell, stream, monads

[`Data.Vector.Stream`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Stream.html) provides an nice `Stream` implementation that is very efficient  thanks to the focus on fusability (see [this paper](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.104.7401) for more). Since `vector-0.1` this `Stream` implementation changed slightly by moving the [`Step`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.1/docs/src/Data-Vector-Stream.html#Step) type into a monad. (Now, the implementation is located in [`Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream.Monadic`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Fusion-Stream-Monadic.html).)

In a nutshell, here's the definition of `Stream`:

```
data Step s a where
    Yield :: a -> s -> Step s a
    Skip  :: s -> Step s a
    Done  :: Step s a

data Stream a = forall s. Stream (s -> Step s a) s
```

`Step s a` encapsulates the three possible results from one iteration of state `s` with update function `s -> Step s a`. The stream is either `Done`, or skips output, or yields output. (The definition above uses GADTs, but that's not relevant, here.)

Simple applications of this `Stream` are:

```
empty :: Stream a
empty = Stream (const Done) ()

singleton :: a -> Stream a
singleton x = Stream step True where
    step True  = Yield x False
    step False = Done

fromList :: [a] -> Stream a
fromList zs = Stream step zs
where
    step (x:xs) = Yield x xs
    step []     = Done
```

Strict left fold is done like this:

```
foldl'S :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> Stream b -> a
foldl'S f a0 (Stream step s) = go a0 s where
    go a s = a `seq`
                case step s of
                    Yield b s' -> go (f a b) s'
                    Skip    s' -> go a       s'
                    Done       -> a
```

and that gives the usual list-like functions `lengthS = foldl'S (\n _ -> n+1) 0`, etc. This certainly isn't as elegant as [`Conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit) or [`Pipes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes), but it's simple and fast. So far so good.

Now, let's try to aggregate 'low-level' streams to more high-level ones. For example, if you have a bitstream `Stream Bool` you may want to decode the bits to yield a `Stream Int` by using some clever codec. Of course it's always possible to build up a new step function `s -> Step s b` from the `step` function extracted of a given `Stream step s`. Repeated applications of the `step :: s->Step s a` function result in awkward `case (step s) of ...` cascades that handle the three possibilities `Done`, `Skip`, `Yield`, over and over again. Ideally, the `aggregate` should like this:

```
aggregate :: Stream a -> M?? -> Stream b
newStream = aggregate oldStream $ do
    a1 <- get    -- a1 :: a
    if a1 == True then doSomething
    else do
        a2 <- get
        -- etc.
```

The `M??` is some monad, to be defined. Let's try a type `Appl s a`:

```
newtype Appl s a = Appl ((s->Step s a) -> s -> Step s a)
```

It's called `Appl` because it has the signature of a function application. The monad instance is quite straightforward:

```
instance Monad (Appl s) where
    return a = Appl (\_ s -> Yield a s)
    (Appl ap) >>= f = Appl (\step s ->
        case (ap step s) of
            Done -> Done
            Skip s' -> untilNotSkip step s'
            Yield a' s' -> ap' step s' where Appl ap' = f a'
```

where `untilNotSkip :: (s->Step s a) -> s -> Step s a` is just repeated (nested) application of a `step :: (s->Step s a)` until a `Done` or a `Yield` is returned.

The `get` function is just normal function application

```
get :: Appl s a
get = Appl(\step s -> step s)
```

To tie things up, `Functor` and `Applicative` need to be done, and here comes the problem: `Appl s` can't be made a functor. The signature is

```
fmap :: (a->b) -> Appl s a -> Appl s b
```

and that just doesn't work because in order to make a function `(s->Step s b) -> s -> Step s b)` from a function `(s->Step s a) -> s -> Step s a)` I'd need a `b->a`. I can pull back an `Appl s b` over an `a->b`, but I can't push forward an `Appl s a` - i.e. I can have a contravariant functor but not a functor. That's weird. Streams [are quite naturally comonads](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2017/01/02/comonads/), but I don't see the connection. the purpose of `Appl` is to turn a step function `s->Step s a` into another one `s->Step s b`.

Something is very wrong here, `Appl` isn't the right "`M??`". Can anyone help out?

**Update**

As pointed out by Li-yao Xia the type should be something like

```
data Walk a b = forall s. Walk ((s->Step s a) -> s -> Step s b)
```

And the Functor, Applicative and Monad instances would be

```
instance Functor (Step s) where
    fmap f Done        = Done
    fmap f (Skip s)    = Skip s
    fmap f (Yield a s) = Yield (f a) s

instance Functor (Walk a) where
    fmap f (Walk t) = Walk ( \step s -> fmap f (t step s) )

-- default Applicative given a monad instance
ap :: (Monad m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
ap mf m = do
    f <- mf
    x <- m
    return (f x)

untilNotSkip :: (s->Step s a) -> s -> Step s a
untilNotSkip step s = case step s of
    Done        -> Done
    Skip s'     -> untilNotSkip step s'
    Yield a' s' -> Yield a' s'

instance Monad (Walk a) where
    return a = Walk (\_ s -> Yield a s)
    Walk t >>= f =
        Walk (\step s -> case t (untilNotSkip step) s of
            Done        -> Done
            Skip _      -> error "Internal error."
            Yield b' s' -> case f b' of Walk t' -> t' step s'   -- bad
    )

instance Applicative (Walk a) where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap
```

The type checker won't allow this monad instance, however. In the definition of `>>=` the `s` in `Walk (\step s -> ...` is different from the `s'` in `Yield b' s' -> ...`, but it must be the same. The fundamental problem here is that `(>>=) :: Walk a b -> (b->Walk a c) -> Walk a c` has two independently all-quantified states `s`, one in the first argument, and another one that is returned by `b->Walk a c`. Effectively this is (with abuse of notation)
`(forall s. Walk s a b) -> (forall s'. b->Walk s' a' c) -> (forall s''. Walk s'' a c)`, which doesn't make sense, neither conceptually nor for the type checker. All three `s`, `s'`, `s''` must be the same type.

A variation where `Walk` is not all-quantified over `s`:

```
data Walk s a b = Walk ((s->Step s a) -> s -> Step s b)
```

allows correct definition of bind, but then `aggregate` won't work:

```
-- does not compile
aggregate :: Stream a -> Walk s a b -> Stream b
aggregate (Stream step s) (M t) = Stream (t step) s
```

Again, the stream state `s` must always be the same. One way out of this would be to introduce a `data PreStream s a = PreStream (s -> Step s a) s`, but that doesn't allow an `aggregate :: Stream a -> ?? -> Stream b` either.

The source code is on [github](https://github.com/mcmayer/stream-transducer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at `Appl` again, because it seems almost right.

```
newtype Appl s a = Appl ((s->Step s a) -> s -> Step s a)
```

The idea is to define a stream transducer by converting a "low-level" step function to a "high-level" one. With that view, those two step functions shouldn't have the same output. For example, if we're transducing bits to bytes, we want `(s -> Step s Bit) -> s -> Step s Byte`.

Thus, a better type would be

```
newtype Walk s b a = Walk ((s -> Step s b) -> s -> Step s a)
-- A walk is many steps.
```

Furthermore, since `Stream` quantifies existentially over `s`, you'll need some universal quantification over `s` at some point to use `Walk`, so you might as well put it in the type definition.

```
newtype Walk b a = Walk (forall s. (s -> Step s b) -> s -> Step s a)
```

Comment: Yes, that sounds good. There is still a problem with the quantification over `s`, though. See the update.

Comment: `forall s. Walk (...)` (`Walk :: forall b a s. ((s -> Step s b) -> s -> Step s a) -> Walk a b`) is an existential type, as opposed to `Walk (forall s. (...))` (`Walk :: forall b a. (forall s. (s -> Step s b) -> s -> Step s a) -> Walk a b`).

Comment: In the first case, the constructor field of `Walk` is monomorphic but part of its type is hidden by the constructor, in the other (correct one), the field is polymorphic.

Comment: In that latter case GHC will complain that `s` escapes its scope in the definition of `>>=`.

Comment: it's on github, the last line of the update to the question has the link. Look at StreamTrans2.hs. (The error won't format well in the comment box...)

Comment: Ah, this is an error caused by `MonoLocalBinds`. Move the `where` block to a `let` block inside `Walk`. `Walk (let t' step s = ... in t')`. By the way, you can call `t'` directly at [line 91](https://github.com/mcmayer/stream-transducer/blob/master/src/StreamTrans2.hs#L91), instead of using `until` to peel off `Skip` events.

Comment: ah, sorry, that was some stuff left over from various experiments. I have to have a deep think about what the difference between `Walk forall s. ...` and `forall s. Walk ...` is.