# Why is this not a case of the restricted monad limitation?

Tags: haskell, monads, ghc

In the following code snippet I initially believed to have a restricted monad error (I forgot to add the `Monad m =>` in the `instance Monad (Transform m a)` definition). Having read quite a bit about restricted monads I wonder why this here happens to be ok:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Next a where
    Todo :: a -> Next a
    Done :: Next a

instance Functor Next where
    fmap f Done = Done
    fmap f (Todo a) = Todo (f a)

data Transform m a b = Monad m => Transform ( m(Next a) -> m(Next b) )

instance Functor (Transform m a) where
    fmap f (Transform ta) = Transform tb where
        tb ma = ta ma >>= return . (fmap f)

instance Applicative (Transform m a) where
    pure = return
    mf <*> ma = do
        f <- mf
        a <- ma
        return (f a)

instance Monad m => Monad (Transform m a) where
    return b = Transform (t b) where                
        t b _ = return $ Todo b
    (Transform t) >>= f = Transform (\ma -> do     
        a <- ma
        case a of
            Done -> return Done
            --Todo a' -> ...
        )
```

The example is rather contrived, I stripped away all irrelevant bits. (The actual problem at hand is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131671/stream-transformer-monad-for-vector-stream).) The crucial part is the `Monad m` restriction in `Transform`.

I don't quite see how this is different from the often-cited canonical `Set`-as-a-monad example, which does exhibit the restricted monad limitation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Transform` is not a restricted monad.

Look at `Set`. `Set` is monadic in its one argument, except said argument needs to be `Ord`. That is, `Set` is a monad on the subcategory of Hask where all the objects are in `Ord`.

But `Transform` is not a monad in the first place. `Transform :: (* -> *) -> * -> * -> *`, but `Monad` applies to things of kind `* -> *` (if you're going to go full category theorist, monads in general are endofunctors and should roughly have kind `k -> k` for some `k`, but `Transform` doesn't really fit that wider template either). The thing that is a monad is `Transform m a` when `m` is a monad. `Transform m a` is monad on all of Hask, as long as `m` is also a monad. You see the difference? `Transform m a` given `Monad m` operates on every type there is. But there is nothing I can put in the blank to make "`Set` given ___ operates on every type there is", because the restriction is going on the parameter that `Set` is monadic in, while `Transform m a` does not have a restriction on the type it is monadic in, but on one of the types that makes it up.

Comment: I wish people would use categorial language more often... Yes, that's clear now!

Comment: Great answer, However I'd like to note that `Set` requires `Ord`, not just `Eq`

Comment: @M.Aroosi fixed.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't quite see how this is different from the often-cited canonical Set-as-a-monad example, which does exhibit the restricted monad limitation.

It's different because the constraint isn't on the last type parameter, which is the one which varies in `Monad`. In the case of `Set` it is.

Comment: That alternate definition is the same one as in the question, no?

Comment: Oh, missed which side the constraint was on, sorry.